# Adding single template block to multiple places

Tags: layout, blocks, template, magento-1.6, static-block

I need to add a small template into multiple places in the store: catalog, search results page, product details page.

Currently in my module's layout file I have:

```
<layout>
    ...

    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template"
                   template="<path_to_my_template>"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>

    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template"
                   template="<path_to_my_template>"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template"
                   template="<path_to_my_template>"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template"
                   template="<path_to_my_template>"/>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>

    ...
</layout>
```

And it works like a charm.

But I do not like this solution, cause it's pretty long. Are there any ways to make the same in more short and beautiful way?

Comment: you can declare it in <default> tag. so it will be used in all sections.

Comment: @Manikandan yes, but I do not need all sections, only these. That's why `<default>` tag does not suit me.

Comment: you need it only in these 4 section?

Comment: @Manikandan yes, only these. I want to know if there is a possibility to make my declaration shorter.

Comment: you can add it in default and use the remove tag where you didn't want this section to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

A lighter way of doing it would be by using a custom handle. This way you only have to update one handle instead of four if you need to change something

```
<layout>
    ...

    <my_custom_handle>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template"
                   template="<path_to_my_template>"/>
        </reference>
    </my_custom_handle>

    <catalog_product_view>
        <update handle="my_custom_handle"/>
    </catalog_product_view>

    <catalog_category_default>
        <update handle="my_custom_handle"/>
    </catalog_category_default>

    <catalog_category_layered>
        <update handle="my_custom_handle"/>
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <update handle="my_custom_handle"/>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>

    ...
</layout>
```

Comment: So there's no way to avoid long lists?

Comment: @GinoPane not that I'm aware of. The solution I posted is the lightest you can't get from what I know

Answer (score 0):

You can declare like this

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
      <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="core/template" name="testdeclare" template="<path_to_my_template>"/>
      </reference>
    </default>

    <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
      <remove name="testdeclare"/>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
</layout>
```

So that it will be used in the pages

Comment: But with this I will need to skip all pages, where I actually do not need that template.

Comment: i have updated the answer by remove tag

Comment: I'm afraid, that `remove` section will be even more long and complicated than my declaration, because I need to list there all other pages.

Moreover, I can not know all pages, where i do not need my template, I only know pages, where I do need it. That's the point.

Thanks anyways.